# Which 20th-century Rosh Yeshiva studied under the mysterious Monsieur Chouchani?

Tags: history, rabbis, yeshiva-school, hashkafah-philosophy

[Monsieur Chouchani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsieur_Chouchani) was a mysterious figure who travelled around post-World War II and taught several great Jewish thinkers, including Emmanuel Levinas z"l and [yibadel l'chayim] Elie Wiesel.

[According to Ha'aretz](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahTzLbx_JMnoJ%3awww.haaretz.com/goodbye-mr-chouchani-1.101330+wiesel+chouchani+yeshiva+answers&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com):

> Wiesel relates how a friend who had studied with him under Chouchani in France warned Wiesel that their teacher wanted to weaken the foundations of their belief and admitted that he found Chouchani frightening. That person, notes Wiesel, later traveled to Brooklyn and became the head of a yeshiva and one of the greatest rabbinical authorities of his generation.

I assume that rosh yeshiva is no longer living(?), so [for history's sake, I'll ask](http://torahmusings.com/2011/03/toward-a-halakhic-philosophy-of-history/): which rosh yeshiva was it?

Comment: anyone want to provide a translation/summary of this interview? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S62uMKl0QrI

Comment: the identity of [Chouchani](http://www.chouchani.com) has been [all but confirmed](http://orot.com/the-mysterious-meir-rav-kooks-missing-student/) as Hillel Pearlman, student of Rav Kook.

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2013/05/rav-kooks-missing-student.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rabbi Menashe Klein is a close friend of Eli Wiesel. Perhaps he is the person meant.

Comment: At the very least, he fits the "rosh yeshiva" and "in Brooklyn" criteria (head of Beth Shearim, in Brooklyn).

Comment: Wow. That would make a great deal of sense, and I never thought of that; hooray for crowd-sourcing! Was he in France post-WWII?

Comment: Definitely fits the bill!

Comment: (I didn't mean to imply that R' Menashe Klein doesn't fit the "one of the greatest rabbinical authorities of his generation" criterion! Of course he does. I simply chose to comment on only the objective criteria.)

Comment: msh210 I never assumed you didn't think so.

Comment: Rabbi Klein is in Israel now.

Comment: Not having known Monsieur Chouchani I can't say for certain, but I can envision a scenario where he didn't sit or fit well with the young Rabbi Klein, who, being Hassidic, did not feel comfortable with this non-Hassidic stranger who was into philosophy and other things that were foreign to his Hungarian Chassidic background. Mr. Wiesel, on the other hand, was much more of a freethinker, so he didn't have the same negative reaction to him.

Comment: Mordechai, is this Rav Menashe Klein of Ungvar? Do you have any more details on their relationship?

Comment: Tzvi - A) Yes, B) Relationship of Elie Wiesel and Rabbi Klein you mean? I recall that Wiesel writes about it in at least one of his books - or perhaps it is in a book about Wiesel. If you google Elie Wiesel plus Rabbi Menashe Klein you will find info.

Comment: Tzvi - Do the same search at google books and you will get additional results including one in French which refers to Shoushani

Answer (score 1):

Everything about the personality would click it was Rav Yitzchak Hutner, but had he ever lived in France? The Lubavitcher Rebbe had been in France, but was he a "rosh yeshiva"?

Comment: I see where the Hebrew Wikipedia article about Chouchani indeed identifies the Lubavitcher Rebbe as one of his students, although that's marked "citation needed." Chronologically, it's just barely possible: the Rebbe lived in Vichy for a few months in 1940, and visited Paris briefly in 1947.

Comment: Rav Hutner, Rav Solvechik, and the Rebbe all where in france and all attended the sorbonne university

Comment: @ST, I think the timeline on this was post-WWII. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ST, I believe you're confusing the Sorbonne for the University of Berlin. The Lubavitcher Rebbe attended the Sorbonne, but spent some time auditing classes in Berlin. Rav Hutner and Rav Soloveichik were in Berlin, never France (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: I stand corrected again
http://daattorah.blogspot.com/2008/08/chabad-lubavitcher-rebbe-rav-hutner.html

Comment: ST, the Rebbe never attended Sorbonne. He attended a different college in Paris. See http://www.biu.ac.il/SOC/so/Golan-Habad_eng.pdf

Comment: Did Reb Hutner? I will tell you the truth though I sm not sure about facts with Professor Freidman

Comment: Just a counter point people knew him granted they might have not known which College 

http://inforebbe.blogspot.com/p/berlin-paris.html

Comment: @Yahu, to the best of my knowledge, the Rebbe attended both the Sorbonne, as well as the Ecole Polytechnique.